# 404 when called with AJAX. But not 404 when accessed using browser

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

An ajax call to an url keep getting 404 Not found. But the url works when accessing using browser.

Screenshots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3jo3.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSoMj.png

The ajax is made from the same domain so it's not cross domain issue.

Does anyone know what could cause this ? Help appreciated!

*this system is built with codeigniter

Comment: It would only make sense to show us the ajax code.   Do you have CodeIgniter's CSRF protection enabled?  If so, then you must pass the value of the CSRF token as part of the ajax data.

Answer (score 1):

Try jQuery.get('//54.169.51.129/checkout/checkshipping')

[image: I did and got a 200 OK]

I think if you enable url query params in the codeigniter config, then that may help depending upon your server setup

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I tried it on my side using the exact command. It's still 404 for me. [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/ES2L8Br.png). I have tried using another internet network, and it's still 404. This is so weird. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Seems like there is some application logic issue. I'm not logged in and nothing is in my card, so it's perhaps something relating to that state. You'll probably hear this a lot but the tests and dev team, maybe even a debugger will be more help at this point as we are all in a black-box without implementation detail on SO. 

Merry Christmas btw

Comment: I still haven't solved this. Thanks and belated Merry Christmas !

Comment: Deal with one thing at a time. So if unauthenticated with empty basket, what happens? Then if authenticated with empty basket? Then with one item, then two separate items in basket and authed (seems to need login to add); then multiple qty for one item & authed; then multiple qty + single product with 2 items & authed etc. It's slow but it could help. Do you not have unit tests or functional tests or end-to-end tests?

Answer (score 0):

The implemented service keeps state so when you call them in different ways (sequence of calls) you should expect possible different behaviour. Call them in the same order and you'll be sweet.

On a side note: this (REST) URI should never return a 404 anyway as you do not refer to a particular entity.

Comment: hi. Thanks for you reply. But I am getting a 404? what does it means by `this (REST) URI should never return a 404 anyway as you do not refer to a particular entity.` ?

Comment: A 404 means "not found" and it relates to an entity is missing. The URI "checkout/checkshipping" does not refer to any entity hence there shouldn't be a 404. REST is a guidance which includes how to format URIs. In your case a URI like GET .../shoppingTransactions/444 makes more sense and it returns a shopping transaction that has a status flag like `ShippingCheckStatus` or so. A 404 would be returned if the shopping transaction 444 doesn't exist; otherwise, you would get a 200 returned.